# How to get the response from Soap UI?

Tags: testing, soap, soapui

I am new to SOAP UI, I am trying Currency Converter project by looking at some online link.I use WSDL URL as

http://www.webservicex.com/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?wsdl

When I run the request with `EUR` and `USD`,  I get output as

`<ConversionRateResult>-1</ConversionRateResult>`

Can anyone help in this please.

Comment: Being new to a tool, have you considered first going through the documentation? http://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/getting-started.html

Comment: Yes I am following same steps mentioned in tht document.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are correctly invoking the service from SOAPUI. `<ConversionRateResult>-1</ConversionRateResult>` response is given back by the service.SOAPUI doesn't have a control over that, it is just a client to that service.